# How can I make my character not speed up when moving farther distances in unity and C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a game and if you want to move, you click the left mouse button, to go to the mouse.
But the tutorial I followed will make the character, for example, it will move 10 inches as fast as it moves 1 inch (Not that I am measuring distance with inches). And so it will go really fast if your mouse is far away. So can anyone help me? Also a precaution, I have been coding unity for 3 weeks now, I don't know much yet. Here is the code I am using

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour {
    Vector3 mousePosition;
    public float movespeed = 0.1f;
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    Vector2 posistion = new Vector2 (0f,0f);

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();


    }


    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
            mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
            mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePosition);
            posistion = Vector2.Lerp(transform.position, mousePosition, movespeed);
            rb.MovePosition(posistion);
        }
        else { movespeed = 0.1f; }
        
    }

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        
    }
        
    }
```

I just need my character o move towards my mouse while it moves. Whoever answers, Thanks!

(By the way, the character basically slides across the screen. (Its a top down game.))

MVP

Uhhh, I didn't know this section was a thing. I have looked all over the internet, and I guess this is a uncommon way of moving a character.

Comment: Here's the problem: `position= Vector2.Lerp(transform.position, mousePosition, movespeed);` this does not control for framerate. One moment your PC might render 100 FPS, another it might only render 30 FPS, depending on what else is happening. The solution to this is to use `deltaTime` which solves for this problem: `position = Vector2.Lerp(transform.position, mousePosition, movespeed * Time.delataTime);`. Also, bear in mind `Lerp` is meant to move between a start and a finish. Usually you'd use it like `t = 0; pos = Vector2.Lerp(startPos, endPos, t); t+= Time.deltaTime;`

Comment: You also lerp between maybe -0.1 of a unit or 1000 units.. you need to find the direction and normalize it

Comment: @Absinthe I don't quite get your answer, are you thinking that the movement speed of my character is different on times? What I need help with is, when put my mouse, for example, 200 units away, it will get there in 1 second, but if it is, again for an example, 400 units away, it will get there in 1 second also. So I kind of need a better way to move forwards towards the mouse. Also, thanks so much for answering! I didn't expect anyone would care to answer.

Comment: That may be an additional problem but please impliment the above logic so we can rule that out too, it's definately a problem. For things to be constant across frames you need `Time.deltaTime` or similar: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html. If that doesn't help report back and we can go from there. Specifically, use `position = Vector2.Lerp(transform.position, mousePosition, movespeed * Time.deltaTime);`.

Comment: Ok, I will work on that today.